# Accessing partial class variables

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I have a partial class which reads a value from in

```
 public partial class getFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{

 string file = AcceptButton.FileName;
}
```

string file  I want to access in a regular class

```
public class 
{
  string _file=file;
}
```

First class being partial class I cant do that. How can I do this?

Comment: `public class test()` won't comile.  It doesn't make sense to have parenthesis there.

Comment: Removing `test()` won't make it compile either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> First class being partial class I cant do that. How can I do this?

The fact that the class is partial has *nothing* to do with this.  From the point of view of an external type it doesn't know (or care) that the class is a partial class.

The reason you can access `file` from some other class is that `file` is private.

To access the member directly you would need that member to be public, and you'd also need an instance of that type.

Having said that, since it seems this is related to as webpage, it doesn't make sense for some other class to be accessing the pages fields in the first place.  What you should be doing is having the constructor or method(s) of `test` accept a parameter of type `string` to which `getFile` can pass in it's `file` field when either creating a `test` object or calling one of its methods.